# Blurry menu text on Macbook Pro 15'' retina display

Tags: qgis, mac, retina

I'm using qgis on my macbook pro and all the text of the submenus/popup windows is displayed a little blurry/pixelated. See this example screenshot:

[image]

Is this a normal behavior on retina displays or is there a fix for this problem?

**Hard facts:**

- macbook pro OS X El Capitan
- qgis 2.12.1-Lyon (installed from http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis)

Comment: Related https://hub.qgis.org/issues/11103

Comment: ok, so at least it seems to be a known problem. Does someone know if upgrading to 2.14 or 2.16 solves this issue?

Comment: I believe this needs Qt5 which is getting implemented for QGIS 3.0 @underdark could confirm see 'What will be the key changes for 3.0?' http://blog.qgis.org/2016/01/17/help-us-to-plan-for-qgis-3-0/

Comment: As far as your posted blog indicates they already implemented qt5 in version 2.16. I might update in the following days and check if it helps...

Comment: 2.16 is still QT4. Only 3.0 will be QT5.